# Why people putting bounty on a question which is old/answered?

Tags: discussion, bounty

From [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893333/multiple-variables-in-python-with-statement) question, I'm wondering why people doing things like this? This question has already an answer? So why people putting bounties on questions like this, old and answered? Did I miss something about bounty system or?

Comment: from the bounty reason box "One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty."  Someone wants to give an answerer some more reps for their good answer.

Comment: So on that question the user who put that bounty, wants to reward the answerer only?

Comment: He wants to reward an existing answer, I'm guessing that it won't go the accepted answer ;)

Comment: Have you ever encountered an answer and wished - "if only I could upvote this 5 times..."? That's when you place a bounty to reward it. To be clear, you are _paying with your own reputation_, which is different from voting, but it is a nice way to reward really excellent answers.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Excatly, I lived that :-) I got it thanks, and is this guaranteed that reputation is goes to accepted answer? or is that goes to answer which is most up-voted?

Comment: The reputation goes to whoever the person awarding the bounty wants to give it to.

Answer (score 3):

As @MichaelBerkowski and @Sompuperoo mentioned in the comments, in this case, the user is rewarding a particularly helpful answer.

A major reason to give bounty is to reward someone even more than an upvote or even marking their question accepted. Recently, on AskUbuntu, I came across an answer that solved an issue I had been working on for many hours, so I upvoted the answer, and ALSO awarded a 50 rep bounty, to thank the user.

Now the reason that you see the bounty is the thing nobody mentioned - you have to wait 2 full days before awards the bounty. It gives you time to think, and also prevents abusive transfer of reputation. That is why you see these once in a while, while there are still 6 or 7 days left in the bounty - the person simply can't award it yet.

Comment: I always leave those for a week anyway. It gives extra exposure and hopefully upvotes to the answer I'm intending to reward.